# What is tiger192,4 in PHP?

Tags: hash

PHP supports hashing of the [following Tiger algorithms](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php):

- tiger128,3
- tiger160,3
- tiger192,3
- tiger128,4
- tiger160,4
- tiger192,4

[Wikipedia's entry on Tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_(cryptography)) says there's Tiger and Tiger2 and provides samples of Tiger and Tiger2 with 192-bit hashes of "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". So I tried to get PHP to tell me what the hashes of `tiger192,3` and `tiger192,4` are and...

The output of tiger192,3 matches what Wikipedia says the output is for Tiger(1). But tiger192,4's output does not match the output for Tiger2.

Tiger2's output is as follows:

```
976abff8062a2e9dcea3a1ace966ed9c19cb85558b4976d8
```

tiger192,4's output is as follows:

```
c1f3a704e9f6267e9f75fa47191f83c354100a04c4f1dc6f
```

tiger192,3 and Tiger's output is as follows:

```
6d12a41e72e644f017b6f0e2f7b44c6285f06dd5d2c5b075
```

So what is tiger192,4?

Comment: hash != mcrypt. PHP has a hash extension that's been built in since PHP 5.1.2: http://php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php mcrypt is it's own thing: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php. I also have no idea what the ",3" or ",4" mean in PHP lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look into the PHP code showed that PHP only understands the Tiger hash (the first one with incorrect bit padding).

It also showed that their implementation of Tiger may contain "additional passes", where each pass consists of 8 rounds (only called for values higher than 3). The value of `passes` is displayed behind the hash function:

```
#define compress(passes) \
    save_abc \
    pass(a,b,c,5) \
    key_schedule \
    pass(c,a,b,7) \
    key_schedule \
    pass(b,c,a,9) \
    for(pass_no=0; pass_no<passes; pass_no++) { \ <- additional rounds start here
        key_schedule \
        pass(a,b,c,9) \
        tmpa=a; a=c; c=b; b=tmpa; \
    } \
    feedforward
```

There seems to be no documentation other than this. Don't use cryptographic primitives that lack any description.

---

I've generated the same `C1...` hash by adding the 8 additional rounds in a Java application (and then deleted said Java implementation).

Comment: Note that attacks have been found on Tiger up to 22 rounds (OK, using around $2^{64}$ memory). That's however too close for comfort, this may have been an ill advised method of fixing that. Or an attempt to create a password hashing function with many iterations - who knows?

Answer (score 3):

This excerpt is directly from the official "Tiger" reference implementation:
https://biham.cs.technion.ac.il/Reports/Tiger/tiger-src.zip

```
/* The number of passes of the hash function.          */
/* Three passes are recommended.                       */
/* Use four passes when you need extra security.       */
/* Must be at least three.                             */
#define PASSES 3
```

```
#define compress \
      save_abc \
      pass(a,b,c,5) \
      key_schedule \
      pass(c,a,b,7) \
      key_schedule \
      pass(b,c,a,9) \
      for(pass_no=3; pass_no<PASSES; pass_no++) { \
          key_schedule \
          pass(a,b,c,9) \
          tmpa=a; a=c; c=b; b=tmpa;} \
      feedforward
```

```
#define pass(a,b,c,mul) \
      round(a,b,c,x0,mul) \
      round(b,c,a,x1,mul) \
      round(c,a,b,x2,mul) \
      round(a,b,c,x3,mul) \
      round(b,c,a,x4,mul) \
      round(c,a,b,x5,mul) \
      round(a,b,c,x6,mul) \
      round(b,c,a,x7,mul)
```

So, **3** passes are the *default*, but more passes are possible for "extra security".

The PHP implementation offers either **3** passes (24 rounds) or **4** passes (32 rounds) and that is perfectly consistent with the original Tiger source code, even though only the *"3 passes"* version matches the "standard" Tiger function. Using **4** passes (32 rounds) probably gives some extra "safety margin" for existing attacks; a hypothetical 22 rounds version has been [broken](https://online.tugraz.at/tug_online/voe_main2.getvolltext?pCurrPk=20716) already.